# Oracle get old and new value from audit table

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have an audit table structure kind of like this (simplified).

```
OID,VALUE,CHANGED_DATE
```

and what I would like to do is write a query that, for each VALUE change, gives me the following output.

```
OLD_VALUE,NEW_VALUE,CHANGED_DATE
```

How would I go about doing that? So, for example, if I had

```
OID|VALUE|CHANGED_DATE
----------------------
1  |ABC  |15-JAN-18
2  |DEF  |22-JUN-18
3  |XYZ  |16-JUL-18
```

I would like to see output like:

```
OLD_VALUE|NEW_VALUE|CHANGED_DATE
--------------------------------
ABC      |DEF      |22-JUN-18
DEF      |XYZ      |16-JUL-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select oid, lag(oid) over (order by changed_date) as prev_oid, changed_date
from t;
```

This code includes all three rows.  If you want to eliminate the first:

```
select *
from (select oid, lag(oid) over (order by changed_date) as prev_oid, changed_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_oid is not null;
```

Comment: @cloudwalker . . . You can choose whichever answer you like (as the OP).  But this answer was posted over four minutes before the other answer.  You can move your mouse over the time above our names to get the exact time (16:04:08 for this one versus 16:08:45 for the other).

Answer (score 1):

You want `lead()` :

```
select t.*
from (select oid, lead(value) over (order by changed_date) as next_value, changed_date
      from table 
     ) t
where next_value is not null;
```